# Regex expression to find a variable in an expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regex which match all variables in an expression, which could only be letters followed by a number, like "x1" or not followed by a number, juste like "z". And I want to find them in expressions where they can be followed by all characters, for example

```
expr = exp(x36)+log(x27)+2*z
```

For example the regex should return [x36, x27, z]

I have tried this :

```
pattern = re.findall("[^a-z][a-z][^a-z](\d?)", expr)
```

where [^a-z][a-z][^a-z] means "not a letter followed by a letter itself followed by not a letter" but it does not seems to work, it returns to me a [] list

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z]\d*\b', exp)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/sKaOGP/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Za-z]                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolasoNT21QsFWoUgpJinaUTcqUbcqNiZFKyZJiasktbgkvrikCCirlFpRoFFhbKapnZOfrlFhZK6pbaRVpcRVUJSZV6JRlKqXlpmXkpiTowE2TkcBplVT8/9/AA)**:

```py
import re
regex = r"\b[A-Za-z]\d*\b"
test_str = "exp(x36)+log(x27)+2*z"
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

**Results**: `['x36', 'x27', 'z']`